# "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" when trying to track Kinect joint

Tags: position, kinect

I want to track a joint position (LeftKnee) from Kinect. The problem is that I get `reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference` on the `Skeleton.Joints` part. Can anyone help me please?

```
Private Sub SensorSkeletonFrameReady(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs)
    Dim skeletons(-1) As Skeleton
    Using skeletonFrame As SkeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame()
        If skeletonFrame IsNot Nothing Then
            skeletons = New Skeleton(skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength - 1) {}
            skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons)
            Dim j As Joint = Skeleton.Joints(JointType.LeftKnee)
        End If
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the `JointType` Enumeration incorrectly.  See the [JointType Enumeration documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.jointtype.aspx) at MSDN for a list of possible enumeration values.

It's `JointType.KneeLeft`, not 'LeftKnee'.